# Python looping for web scraping

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from **[a website](http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-wa/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true/)**.

The code i have written is

```
import csv

import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-
  retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure+medical+consulting-other-in-wa/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Address_1 = soup.find('p', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel__address'})

Address = Address.text.strip()
```

The result i am getting is

```
 'GF 255 Adelaide TerracePerth, WA 6000'
```

which is just one line of address of one listing.

When I am using `soup.find_all`, I am getting the result like:

```
 p class="details-panel__address" data-reactid="90"><span class="details-
 panel__address-text text-truncate" data-reactid="91">GF 255 Adelaide 
 Terrace</span><span class="details-panel__address-text text-truncate" data-
 reactid="92">Perth, WA 6000</span></p

  p class="details-panel__address" data-reactid="122"><span class="details-
 panel__address-text text-truncate" data-reactid="123">369-371 Oxford 
 Street</span><span class="details-panel__address-text text-truncate" data-
 reactid="124">Mount Hawthorn, WA 6016</span></p>,

  p class="details-panel__address" data-reactid="148"><span class="details-
 panel__address-text text-truncate" data-reactid="149">2 Lloyd Street</span>
 <span class="details-panel__address-text text-truncate" data-
 reactid="150">Midland, WA 6056</span></p>,

  p class="details-panel__address" data-reactid="172"><span class="details-
 panel__address-text text-truncate" data-reactid="173">Bluenote Building, 16/162 
 Colin Street</span><span class="details-panel__address-text text-truncate" 
 data-reactid="174">West Perth, WA 6005</span></p>,

  p class="details-panel__address" data-reactid="196"><span class="details-
 panel__address-text text-truncate" data-reactid="197">Bluenote Building, 10/162 
 Colin Street</span><span class="details-panel__address-text text-truncate" 
 data-reactid="198">West Perth, WA 6005</span></p>
```

Please suggest what I should do to extract the information regarding address, property type, Sold Date, Sales Value, Area, Agency Name, Agent's Name & Phone Number of all the listings on this page. Also, I do not know how to use loop to open each listing on a particular page and get the information out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`soup.find_all` return list of elements.To get the text you have to iterate over the list of elements to extract the text with `text` attribute.

```
import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("""http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-
  retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure+medical+consulting-other-in-wa/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true""")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Address_1 = soup.find_all('p', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel__address'})
address_list = [ address.text.strip() for address in Address_1]
print(address_list)
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel'})
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]
print(hrefs)
# Now iterate through the list of urls and extract the required data
```

Comment: Can you please also let me know that how can i use loop to open each listing & get the data within that link ?

Comment: Is there any way , i can create loop to open up each listing & extract information from with in ?

Comment: I am unable to write the code for looping to extract information from each link of the listing. Please help me with what should i add to the below code so that i can extract Address, Sold Date, Area, Agency name, Agent Name & Agent Contact number from with in each link.

Comment: import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-wa/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Address_1 = soup.find_all('p', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel__address'})
Address = [ Address.text.strip() for Address in Address_1]

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated